# Adding a prefix for each value in JSON dump

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm creating a lexer which creates tokens and outputs them as a JSON list. The tokens are namedtuples.

More specifically, `Token = namedtuple('Token', ['kind', 'lexeme'])`

I create my tokens and print them using `json.dumps(tokens, separators=(',', ':')))`.

The output looks like this:

```
[
    [
      "INT",
      "123"
    ],
    [
      "ID" 
      "b32"
    ],
]
```

I am looking to add a 'kind' and 'lexeme' label so that it looks like:

```
[
    [
      "kind" : "INT",
      "lexeme" : "123"
    ],
    [
      "kind" : "ID" 
      "lexeme" : "b32"
    ],
]
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `namedtuple` to `dict` before running `json.dumps()`.

```
json.dumps([t._asdict() for t in tokens], separators=(',', ':'))
```

This should generate:

```
[
    {
      "kind" : "INT",
      "lexeme" : "123"
    },
    {
      "kind" : "ID",
      "lexeme" : "b32"
    }
]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY27CsIwFIb3PMXZTgKloN0ENxcXp26lSGwixjY5ITkFffraeAG3n@@/xSffKDTLck3kYaBpsgM7Chmcj5QYgvbW8BwnK77knikI0dJoA@z/fIlvhhV0OLpgVoGTfVhvsVdCcDHz2ujeMYnHU1sim22DqoIfPBR2abaoemE067VQDmsz@5hlx/VZZ@MGlgqulIDBBfhM9xVkG3XSTCnvJVZlaYdq/Y7JBZZlTi3LCw)

Comment: Thank you my friend.